# $u_j \rightarrow u$ and $||Tu_j||$; exists sequence $w_k$ such that $Tw_k $ converge in norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $T:dom(T) \rightarrow H$ be a densely defined operator. Suppose there is a sequence $\{u_j \}$ in the domain of $T$ such that $u_j \rightarrow u$, and $||Tu_j||$ is bounded, prove that exists elements $w_k \rightarrow u$, such that $Tw_k \rightarrow \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in H$.

The proof I am given is as follows:

1. we take a subsequence $u_{j_k}$ such that $\{ Tu_{j_k} \}$ is weakly convergent in $H$.
2. Observe weak and norm closure of convex sets coincide.
3. By consdiering the convex hull of $\{Tu_{j_k}\}$ there is a **suitable sequence** sequence $w_k$ each of which is convex combination of $\{u_{j_k}\}$ such that $Tw_k$ converges in norm.

I could see how we can choose $w_k$ such that $Tw_k$ converges in norm. But I don't see why we can choose such that $w_k \rightarrow
 u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(Tu_j)$ is bounded, so it has a weakly convergent subsequence, say, $(Tu_{j_k})$. By a theorem of [Banach-Saks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Banach%E2%80%93Saks_theorem), a weakly convergent sequence in a Hilbert space has a subsequence whose arithmetic means converge in norm. Therefore, there is a further subsequence, denoted for simplicity by  $(Tu_l)$, such that the sequence
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^nTu_l$$
converges in norm.
Put $w_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^nu_l$. Since $u_k$ converges to $u$, so does its subsequence $u_l$, and so does the sequence of means $w_n$. Thus, $Tw_n$ converges in norm, and $w_n$ converges to $u$, as required.

Comment: Sorry, but how does any sequence of convex combination converge to $u$? What if the convex combination was something like 

$$ 1/2 u_1 + 1/2 u_k $$ 
which converges to $1/2u_1 + 1/2 u $?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I didn't mean such trivialities. See the corrected answer.